# Python; Writing data to CSV not consistently ordered by fieldname

Tags: python, csv

Python 3.11.4

I am trying to write data to a csv file that has 5 field names. When writing the data to the csv the data is not consistently going into the correct field. The table below is to help visualize the issue.

| DriveLetter | DriveSpace |
| --- | --- |
| 350GB | C |
| C | 350GB |

```
class CSVWriter:
    def __init__(self, filename, fieldnames):
        self.filename = filename
        self.fieldnames = fieldnames
        self.file_exists = os.path.exists(self.filename)
        
        if not self.file_exists:
            self.file = open(self.filename, 'w', newline='')
            self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            self.writer.writeheader()
        else:
            self.file = open(self.filename, 'a', newline='')
            self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    def write_row(self, data):
        ordered_data = {key: data[key] for key in self.fieldnames}
        self.writer.writerow(ordered_data)

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()
```

This is the class for writing to the csv. Things I tried to get the columns to match up was add the ordered_data variable in the write_row function. From what I have found it looks like the csv.DictWriter should have kept the order by field names.

The data dictionary order matches with the order of the fieldnames. Any help would be appreciated.

Example of data being passed into write_row():

```
fieldnames = {'Date', 
          'DriveLetter', 
          'FreeSpace', 
          'TotalSpace', 
          'PercentFree'}

csv_write = CSVWriter(filename=csv_path, fieldnames=fieldnames)

drive_info = {'Date': now,
        'DriveLetter': driveLetter, 
        'FreeSpace': freeSpace, 
        'TotalSpace': totalSpace, 
        'PercentFree': percentFree
        }


csv_write.write_row(drive_info)



csv_write.close()
```

Comment: Please share an example of the value of `data`, as it is passed to `write_row()`

Comment: @S3DEV I am using 3.11.4

Comment: @Grismar I edited the post with code snippets of data being passed to write_row().

Comment: Use a list or tuple for `fieldnames`, not a set. Sets aren't ordered.

Comment: @Barmar That was the issue! I knew it was going to be something stupid like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list or tuple for fieldnames, not a set. Sets aren't ordered.